# Function Powers

Tags: c++

I have to write a main( ) routine to test the results of the following test cases:

power(8, 2)

power(3, 3)

power(2, 10)

Use cout to display the computed values on screen.
This is what I have done so far but its not working for me

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int pwr (int&, int);

int main ()
{
int m, n;
cout << "Enter two positive integers;";
cin >> m >> n;
cout << endl << "The power is " << pwr(m,n) << endl;
return 0;
}

int power (int m, int n)
{
if (n<=1)
    return m;
else
    return m * power (m, n-1);
}
```

Comment: Not working means absolutely nothing.

Comment: `int pwr (int&, int)` is declared but never defined. `int power (int m, int n)` is defined but never used.

Comment: Mankarse and Song Wang both have given you your answer. I am assuming that this is for homework. Try and input a character instead of a number and look at the output.

Comment: Don't give us code that doesn't even compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No need to include `cmath`
2. function declaration and definition mismatch `int pwr (int&, int)`  vs `int power (int m, int n)` (name mismatch and argument mismatch)
3. recursive calling function `return m * power (m, n-1)` should be the correct one either `pwr` or `power` .
4. Use some meaningful function names and variable names.
5. Use indent and brackets to make your code clear.

---

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int getPower(int, int);

int main ()
{
    int value, power;
    cout << "Enter two positive integers;";
    cin >> value >> power;
    cout << "The power is " << getPower(value,power) << endl;
    return 0;
}

int getPower (int value, int power)
{
    if (power<=1){
        return value;
    }
    else{
        return value * getPower (value, power-1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Is `int pwr (int&, int);` supposed to be `int power (int m, int n)`?

Perhaps the code is supposed to be like this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int pwr (int, int);

int main ()
{
int m, n;
cout << "Enter two positive integers;";
cin >> m >> n;
cout << endl << "The power is " << pwr(m,n) << endl;
return 0;
}

int pwr (int m, int n)
{
if (n<=1)
    return m;
else
    return m * pwr (m, n-1);
}
```

Comment: If U use C++11 (Visual Studio 2015 or newer), perhaps you could impress your teacher by the use of constexpr or even templates. Have a look here for an alternative way of doing what you intend... Also, please try to STFG before you ask a question. Not clogging the namespace with general question titles will be a great help for others in long run. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You declare your function as

```
int pwr (int&, int);
```

but you are defining it as

```
int power (int m, int n)
```

So the compiler cannot find the function `pwr` inside `main`.

Change the function definition to the following:

```
 int pwr(int m, int n)
 {
   if (n<=1)
      return m;
   else
      return m * pwr (m, n-1);
 }
```

Since you are dealing with `int`s, you don't need to pass by reference.